# Horizontal Flatlist: Space between items

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to get space around my items in a horizontal flatlist, no matter how I try it doesn't seem to work:

```
const renderItem = ({item}) => {

return (
  <View style={styles.item}>
    <Image
      source={{uri: content.uri}}
      style={styles.image}
    />
    <View>
      <Text style={styles.contentTitle}>{content.title}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.contentText}>{content.releaseDate}</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
)
   
}

<View style={styles.container}>
  {header}
  <View style={{width: '100%', justifyContent: 'space-around', backgroundColor: 'green'}}>
     <FlatList
        data={data}
        pagingEnabled={true}
        horizontal={true}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        ref={flatList}          
      />
  </View>   
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: windowWidth,
    marginTop: 15,
    paddingBottom: 15,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: Colors.borderBlue,
    backgroundColor: Colors.backgroundGenericTransparent,
  },
  item: {
    width: windowWidth / 3.1,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
  image: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 220,
  },
})
```

result:

[image]

As you can see the items are all together on the left even though I have added a space-around property on the container. Not show how I can resolve this.

Comment: Add margin to styles.item ?

Comment: the `justify-content : space-around` CSS property works on a flex-displayed container. So make sure the View on which you add the property `justify-content: space-around` has also `display: flex`. Moreover to have space between each item, you should rather do `justify-content: space-between`

Comment: Adding margin of course works but I'd like to use the 'space-around' property to auto-calculate the margin, just for neatness.

All Views already have the display flex property, I tried adding it but it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 3):

use  `ItemSeparatorComponent`

```
<FlatList
    data={data}
    pagingEnabled={true}
    horizontal={true}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
    ref={flatList}
    ItemSeparatorComponent={() => {
        return (
            <View
                style={{
                    height: "100%",
                    width: 10,
                }} />
        );
    }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this prop on flatlist:

```
columnWrapperStyle={{ justifyContent: "space-between" }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve.
Is that what you want?

snack [here](https://snack.expo.dev/bbt1efhUS)

Just add horizontal padding to your container. and no matter how big your items get you will always have spacing left and right. If the item gets too big you can start to scroll.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `contentContainerStyle` as a parent and style it accordingly.

---

Check this example below.

```
<FlatList
  data={data}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
  contentContainerStyle={styles.listWrapper}
  horizontal
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
  scrollEnabled={false}
  renderItem={({ item, idx }) => <Text>{item}</Text>}
/>;
```

---

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  listWrapper: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    alignItems: "center",
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

This will add an even space in between your listed items

Answer (score -1):

```
    <View style={styles.messageGalleryContainer}>
                <FlatList
                    data={files}
                    renderItem={renderImageGalleryItem}
                    keyExtractor={(item) => item?._id}
                    horizontal
                    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                    ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={{ width: 10 }} />} // add this line
                    contentContainerStyle={styles.messageGalleryItemContainer}
                />
            </View>
```

You should use **ItemSeparatorComponent** with an empty component or with any element you want.

Comment: Please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc.—copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?